# Starting vim-fugitive from command line

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

I really like Fugitive (VIM git wrapper plugin) However I would like to create a script that starts vim and then runs

```
:Gstatus
```

immediately. However when I try

```
vim -c Gstatus
```

I get an error stating that **Gstatus is not an editor command**

Comment: At that point in your session, the fugitive plugin is probably not loaded or unable to work its magic. Can you do `:GStatus` right after you started Vim without any file?

Comment: It seems fugative doesn't work unless there is a file loaded which is part of a git repository. The current directory satisfies that condition so starting gvim with the current directory as the current file works. See My answer below.

Answer (score 6):

`vim +Gstatus +only` works. I have it aliased to `vimg`

Comment: This is perfect, though `+Gstatus` is now deprecated in favor of `+Git`

Comment: `+Gstatus` is deprecated. Instead do `vim +Git +only`

Answer (score 4):

This works

```
gvim -c 'Gstatus | wincmd j | hide' .
```

makes the fugative window full size and hide the directory explorer buffer. Also with the directory buffer hidden when you quit the fugative buffer vim closes

Comment: I prefer using `vim -c Gstatus .` since gives me a window to see diffs (pressing `D` on the cursor line) without closing the status window.

Comment: The `.` directory trick doesn't work when NERDTree plugin is enabled, but `.` can be replaced by any other filename that doesn't exist.

Comment: Just YFI for PowerShell/Windows users - `.` did NOT work for me as the file argument to Vim, so as Ricardo suggested,  all I did was use `temp` as the file name. (Vim only creates the swap file for `temp`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (assuming you are in the project root dir):

```
$ vim -c 'view .git/index'
```

It opens the git index in read-only mode (mimicking the essentials of the :Gstatus command)

Comment: You don't have the rich mappings available like with `:Gstatus` but it works for committing.

Answer (score 1):

As a slight improvement on bradgonesurfing's answer

```
vim -c 'Gstatus | wincmd o' .
```

This works even if you have `splitbelow` set

Answer (score 0):

Run `vim +Git +only`

I got here thanks to @jsm3031's answer, which nudged me in the right direction.